# How to add momentjs to a minified bundle file?

Tags: javascript, dojo, requirejs, bundle, momentjs

I am going to add `momentjs` library in a project (and its `moment-timezone` plugin). In this project I'm using `dojo` and its AMD loader (very similiar to `requirejs`) to work in debug mode. But for production environment I have created three minified bundles: one with all external libraries (as `jquery`, `bootstrap` and other plugins), another one with a private js framework and the third one which contains the specific code for the application.

Well, in development mode there is no problem with `momentjs` because after defined its path in the configuration file it is loaded properly, but I would like to add it to the external bundle file. And it's here where I'm having problems because although the bundle file contains the `momentjs` code, both files `moment.js` and `moment-timezone-with-data.js` are loaded too because they are required at the beginning of a module.

To solve this issue with similar files I use the conditional load of files. This works, for instance, for `jquery`: if I'm debugging the library is explicitely loaded. If I'm not debugging, I assume that it is loaded through a bundle file, and it works because `$` is loaded as a global variable.

Here comes the **origin of my problem**: `momentjs` does a check at the beginning in order to see if `define` function is defined:

```
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
    global.moment = factory()
}(this, function () { 
    'use strict';
    [...] 
});
```

Obviously, `define` function is defined by `dojo` and that provokes the `momentjs` must be loaded always as a amd module and that causes that its file to be loaded even in production environment. So how could I avoid this issue without modify the original source code? I've thought that if it were loaded as a global variable, it should work, but is there any other way to solve this?

Sorry about this large post, but I've tried to exlpain as better as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a library that detects an AMD loader and declares itself as an AMD module only if the loader is present, and want to load this library so that it does not declare itself as an AMD module, then you need to load this library in a `script` element *before* you load the AMD loader.

Alternatively, must load your library *after* your AMD loader is loaded , you could temporarily undefine `define` and define it again afterwards:

```
<script>
    my_variable_for_saving_define = define;
    window.define = undefined;
</script>
<script [that loads your module]></script>
<script>
    define = my_variable_for_saving_define;
</script>
```

`my_variable_for_saving_define` is for illustration purposes. Choose something reasonably likely to not cause a clash.

Comment: I've tested your approach and it works (I have to review my bundle file in order to solve any other issues, but the post problem is resolved). However I'm wondering if there is any more elegant solution, because this one seems a little tricky, no?

Comment: If I knew a more elegant solution, it would be in my answer. :) I could see someone implementing a plugin for RequireJS that could formalize it but I'm not aware of such plugin. (And I'm not sure there is no insurmountable obstacle to the creation of such plugin.)